# What's a reverse of a set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

say I have  $C = \{\epsilon, aa, aab, bba\}$, what would be the reverse of set C?
Is it $C^R = \{bba, aab, aa, \epsilon\}$? but I think the order in a set doesn't matter. Or it is $C^R = \{\epsilon, aa, baa, abb\}$?

Comment: In mathematics, order doesn't matter, but in some programming languages, a set has order.

Comment: The term "reverse of a set" has no standard meaning.  Did you encounter this term in some particular context?

Comment: the example given is a random string, say $(cup)^R = puc$

Comment: Then $cup$ is not a set, it's a string. If you have a set of strings, perhaps you want the corresponding set of the reversed strings. but that's not the reverse of the set; it's the set of the reversed elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "reverse" of a set, but you might want $X$ \ $C$ where $X$ is the domain of $C$. In this case, it's called the *complement* of the set and consists of all elements in $X$ but not in $C$. So if your domain $X$ is $\{\epsilon,a,b,aa,ab,bb,aaa,aab,aba,abb,baa,bab,bba,bbb\}$, then the *complement* of $C$, $X$ \ $C$, is $\{a,b,ab,bb,aaa,aba,abb,baa,bab,bbb\}$.